# Java: style compability tradeoff

Tags: java, switch-statement

I was wondering the other day about the compatibility and style of my Java code. As of Java 14, the enhanced `switch` has really become available. I have attached this below for comparison. Now I find it questionable if you should really use this *good* style, because you would have to compile in Java version 14 in this case. In my experience, few people that needed to run my code actually used a higher version than Java 8. Is there a general rule to determine on which language level code should be written?

```java
int a = 42;

// Old switch
switch(a) {
case 42:
    // Do something
    break;
default:
    // Do something else
}

// New enhanced switch
switch (a) {
    case 42 -> {
        // Do something
    }
    default -> {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: you can specify the target JVM version at compile time with the -target option or in various build systems (maven, gradle, etc.) so you could compile your Java 14 syntax code to be executed in a Java 8 JVM

Comment: Are you writing a library for public consumers or for other internal developers? If it's all part of your internal projects, then the only question to answer is *have you migrated your projects to Java 14+?*

Comment: When it comes to compilation, I'm more concerned with consumers who may only have a low version of Java installed, yet of course I want my code to be as good as possible.

Comment: If you have customers who need to compile your code using JDK 8, then the answer is simple: use the old style that the JDK 8 compiler understands. There's no way to make the compiler from JDK 8 understand the new syntax.

Comment: This boils down to the question, is *your* software required to run on Java 8, which *we* can’t answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the new `switch` statement and expression syntax won't work on older versions of Java.  So that means that you need to consider whether you *need* your code to compile and run on older versions of Java.

But this is not a new problem.  For example in Java 5, they introduced a number of new Java language constructs including generics, annotations, autoboxing and so on.  And Java 7 introduced try with resources.  And Java 8 introduced lambda expressions.  Java is evolving.

It is up to each programmer / project to decide when to start using new language features ... according to their specific requirements and constraints.   We can't really advise you because we don't know what your requirements and constraints are.

But if you take too long to switch to using newer language features, you might end up with an code base with far too much old fashioned clunky code; e.g. explicit boxing/unboxing, raw types, flaky resource cleanup in `finally` blocks and so on.  Ultimately your productivity suffers.

(And the corollary is that you need to make a judgment on how much benefit you will get in productivity and long term maintainability from each new language feature you are considering.  Some will be less beneficial than others.)

---

> When it comes to compilation, I'm more concerned with consumers who may only have a low version of Java installed ...

The flipside is that there are additional costs >to you< in supporting customers who can't or (more likely) don't want to upgrade to a more recent Java platform.  At a certain point, it is best for everyone if you declare old versions of Java to be "no longer supported" for your product.  (But we can't tell you when to do that.  There are too many unquantifiable variables ...)

Comment: As a rough rule of thumb: application projects *can* be more aggressive with switching (since they tend to control the JVM they run on) and library project *tend* to be conservative (i.e. stay with older language versions longer) to provide the widest possible compatibility. Exceptions exist in both directions.